# Communication between JavaFx Scene and GWT-Website

Tags: gwt, interface, javafx

I am using a JavaFx Scene to display my Web Application. For creating the web application, I have used GWT.

I know that JavaFx supports JS-Scene communication, but I don't know what to do so the GWT compiler will create code that can interact with the scene.

Is there some kind of interface technology that can solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bridge between a Java Applet running in the browser and the browser's JavaScript engine. The so called LiveConnect specification describes how JavaScript code communicates with Java code.

Check out the Java Tutorials [Invoking Applet Methods From JavaScript Code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html) and [Invoking JavaScript Code From an Applet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingJavaScriptFromApplet.html).

There is also the GWT third party library [GwtAI](http://code.google.com/p/gwtai/) you might want to have a look at.

Comment: Hey Adrian, thanks for the reply! I came across those techniques as well while I was looking for a Solution to my problem, but JavaFx had those abilities as well. I rather needed a way to interact with the randomly obfuscated JS generated by my GWT Compiler, but this way too complicated for me as I don't know how the GWT compiler actually works. In the meantime I decided to reimplement my client as a standalone JFX Application, which also worked quite well. But thanks anyway, your solution seems to be at least the closest to what is possible.